# Operating system (Home Assistant OS) won't load anymore

Tags: linux

I'm running [Home Assistant OS](https://github.com/home-assistant/operating-system) on a Raspberry Pi 4b. A couple of days ago, I lost connectivity, it won't boot anymore. When I connect a HDMI cable, I don't see anything, monitor doesn't even say it's connected to anything (caveat, I have never used an external monitor on that installation so it might just not be set up). I tried 2 different RPi 4b with the same SD card so it likely isn't an issue with the Pi. The router says the Pi's particular MAC isn't connected either.

I put the SD card with the OS in another linux machine but my debugging skills are still limited.

When I run `fsck` I get the following output:

```bash
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sde
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sde

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sde
```

Here's what `parted` says:

```bash
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name              Flags
 1      1049kB  34.6MB  33.6MB  fat16        hassos-boot       msftres
 2      34.6MB  59.8MB  25.2MB               hassos-kernel0
 3      59.8MB  328MB   268MB                hassos-system0
 4      328MB   353MB   25.2MB               hassos-kernel1
 5      353MB   622MB   268MB                hassos-system1
 6      622MB   630MB   8389kB               hassos-bootstate
 7      630MB   731MB   101MB   ext4         hassos-overlay
 8      731MB   63.9GB  63.1GB  ext4         hassos-data
```

Trying to find how much free space I got I tried doing this which does show some partitions are at 100%:

```bash
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde1 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1        32M  7.5M   25M  24% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde2 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde2       9.7M  9.7M     0 100% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde3 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde3       132M  132M     0 100% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde4 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde4       9.8M  9.8M     0 100% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde5 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde5       132M  132M     0 100% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde6 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
mount: /home/xxxx/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde7 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde7        85M  359K   78M   1% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$ sudo mount /dev/sde8 tmp/ && df -h tmp/ && sudo umount tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde8        58G   17G   40G  30% /home/xxxx/tmp
xxxx@xxxx:~$
```

According to https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/operating-system/partition/,  `/dev/sde6` should be the `Bootstate` partition, so that could be a reason why I can't mount it. Some of the partitions do show 100% use but I'm not sure if that's a red herring or actually the root cause, e.g. some might be swap partitions for which 100% use might make sense based on my limited understanding.

What does this mean for the state/health of the file system or how could I find out more?

Comment: regarding `fsck` "problem" ... `/dev/sde` is the raw disk, so, it has no filesystem. As for not showing a thing when booting, that shouldn't happen. What do the power/status LED's do when you power on? Have you tried booting a regular raspberry pi OS?

Comment: This is vague.  What does "I tried 2 different RPi 4b with the same SD card so it likely isn't an issue with the Pi." mean?  Did the other Pi's boot or not?